# Shade cursed mace

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there a way I can make my ebony mace look like it has a curse on it, kind of like the effect of the ebony mail but on a mace

Comment: Couple issues:

  - Ebony Mail doesn't have a curse to begin with.
  - Ebony Mail's effect is unique to the specific armor.

Not entirely clear what you even want to begin with.

Comment: I am looking for a way to make my weapon look like it was a dark mist around it, like the cursed weapons in shadow of war, I want that visual effect, similar to the way the ebony mail looks, not it's specific enchantment

Answer (score 1):

If you are on PC, there are mods for this.   There is at least one mod which makes the enchantment effects more pronounced, but no matter what, you may want a mod that allows you to disenchant the Mace of Molag Bal or the Ebony Mail.  For the latter, you will need a mod that allows you to apply armor enchants to weapons.

I would recommend learning the ropes of the editor, though, and just creating an enchantment effect that uses the particle scripts for the Ebony Mail.  There is a mod which does this by example for a sash; the Ritual Armor of Boethiah .

Answer (score 1):

For PC: Yes. There are tons of Mods you can use for enchanting. The Black Magic mod allows you to specifically add Curses to your items and armor (These will affect your opponent rather than your character).

For Xbox 360: No. The Ebony Mail cannot be unenchanted and so you cannot get this enchantment.

For Xbox One: Yes/No. While there are mods available to you they aren't always as full fledged as the Nexus Mods on PC. The Black Magic mod is not yet available on Xbox One but "Extra Enchantments" is.

For PlayStation: Yes. The mods are available like Black Magic and Extra Enchantments. There is also the "Unholy" Mod which specifies in curses.